# Having JSF spit out an HTML Search field. Doable?

Tags: java, jsf, html

I'm not a Java developer, but work with a team that is using JSF 1.2

We'd like to start using HTML 5 tags and attributes. It does not appear that JSF 1.2 supports those by default.

Is there anyway to have a JSF text tag:

```
<x:inputText>
```

spit out an html 5 search tag:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="blahblah" />
```

Right now, I'm having to let it output a regular text field and then I place inline JS after it to trigger a function that converts it client side:

```
<input type="text">
<script> funciton here that changes type to 'search' and adds placeholder attribute</script>
```

It works, but is a bit hacky. Is there a legitimate way to get server-side JSF to output proper HTML 5 tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [custom component](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnavg.html). This allows you fine grained control over rendered HTML.

Or upgrade to JSF 2.0, then you can create a [composite component](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) which is [a lot easier](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu-1010/).

Comment: Looks like getting out team to investigate composite components is the way to go. Thanks!